# PC Only boots in safe mode/reboots when the windows splash screen shows

Tags: windows-7, bios

ive posted this on other sites and thought id give this a try.

First, thanks in advance for any help. I know this seems like an simple and common problem, and maybe it is but ive been at it too long to see straight.

I have a PC which i built five years ago. It's worked fine up until yesterday, i shutdown as normal, went to bed and turned it on next day - no boot.

I have several NVMe's, two are bootable with windows 7 partitions. I can get into BIOS, but no NVMe drives are selectable for the boot order. However, if i F12, i can select the NVMe to boot from. If i do this, windows starts loading and displays the splash screen, but then reboots back to bios.

If i F12 > select the NVMe > F8 > safe mode with networking = boots into safe mode fine.

Although this usually implies recent software/driver install issues, i havnt installed or updated anything for months. I did try a restore point to be sure, but it didnt fix the issue.

I did notice the bios settings seemed unusual, almost like the CMOS battery died and reset as originally no NVMe's were showing in the F12 menu. After enabling CSM in the BIOS and selecting UEFI only boots, they did show up again.

Secure boot is disabled, CSM enabled (legacy then UEFI, although ive tried all combos of legacy only, legacy UEFI, EUFI legacy, EUFI EUFI)

In safe mode I have done a 'sfc /scannow' and DISM /online check, clean, restore commands to cover my bases. No difference.

The fact that i can boot safemode, and that it was working fine a couple of days ago leads me to my main school of thought, something in the BIOS aint right. But ill be damned if i know what. only other thing i can think to do is mbr command to fix and repair boot record - however im sure that if it was the boot record then safemode wouldnt work.

mobo = Gigabyte x399 gaming 7.

I thought i'd try a clean install on the new SSD, i made a USB installer with rufus and then booting from the USB installer, same behaviour, reboots when it gets to 'starting windows', so it cant load the PXE. This pushes me more to believing its a BIOS thing.

I have Win 10 on another SSD and it will boot into that just fine. but i need 7 for some older software that only runs there (and some older games).

Any help appreciated

addition: i also just partitioned the win 10 SSD and installed win 7 to that - after the expanding of files and reboot to finish the install - rebooted at the 'starting windows' screen

BIOS was reset and then optimised defaults tried also

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Something to know up-front: This is not a threaded forum, this is a Question and Answer site. Your goal right now, to give you the best chance of getting good answers, is to make your question as clear and complete as possible. The main way you do this is by using the EDIT button as often as you please to add information to the question. Like that comment you just posted; that should be added to the question itself.

Comment: Have you tried to reset the BIOS?

Comment: Also remember that Windows 7 will not run on newer machines. Use a VM for Windows 7

Comment: Yes, BIOS has been reset. Win 7 had worked on this machine for the last 5 years.